# How to open a specific JSP page in iframe on click of a particular button

Tags: javascript, function, jsp, iframe, html

I am using a javascript function to create aniframe, but its not working.

I have 4 buttons on the main page (using JSP). I want to open 4 different pages within the same window below that(we can think it as header and footer).
`onClick` of any of the 4 buttons(that are in the header part) one respective page should open within the same page (in footer part).
on above (can say as in header part) I have some textboxes and want to keep them on every page.
I am using an `iframe`. One has the static `src` i.e `src="index.jsp"` and the "footer" one I want to open a different page as per click .

I am using the header iframe as -

```
<iframe id='header_iframe' style="width: 100%; height:250px;" src="index.jsp" name="iframe_main" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

I am using javascript function to create iframe, but its not working

as-

```
function setIframe()
{
   var demo_Iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
   demo_Iframe.src = "http://localhost:8084/project/demo.jsp";
   demo_Iframe.id="demo_Iframe";
   demo_Iframe.width="100%";
   demo_Iframe.height="400px";
   document.appendChild(demo_Iframe);
}
```

I am calling `setIframe()` on `onclick` event of button.

Comment: `element.appendChild(demo_Iframe);` where is the `element` variable defined in your javascript? I hope you are using firebug or other developer tools to find out javascript errors.

Comment: sorry... i mistaken. it's-

 document.appendChild(demo_Iframe);

it's not working. please suggest how to achieve it or any other approach.
thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(demo_Iframe);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/npkMtG?p=preview)

Comment: P Jhony
heyy..thanks a lot man..
it's working.
thnks for your time :)

Comment: the scenario is that- i am already having one page opened on main page.
now i want that when user click on any of 4 available button on that alredy opened main page..the respective page should be opened below that..it should the another page below that...rather it's moving on to my another jsp page..
please assist !!!!